# Unit Testing a class that uses RegistryManager C# Azure IoTHub

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, mocking, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to test my class that uses `RegistryManager` to communicate with IoThub.

The problem I'm facing is that when creating a mock class that inherits from `RegistryManager` I'm able to override all the methods except for `ExportRegistryAsync`. I get a red line under override and if I remove the override statement I get this error when I build the project:

> Error    4    'MockObjects.MockRegistryManager' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager.ExportRegistryAsync(string, string)'    Tests\MockObjects\MockRegistryManager.cs    9    18

Code:

```
public class MockRegistryManager : RegistryManager
{
    private static List<Device> _devices;

    public MockRegistryManager()
    {
        _devices = new List<Device>();
    }

    public override Task OpenAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    ...


    internal override Task ExportRegistryAsync(string storageAccountConnectionString, string containerName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal override Task ExportRegistryAsync(string storageAccountConnectionString, string containerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to test a class that uses `RegistryManager`?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by red line under override? is it compiling or not if you override?

Comment: you could abstract the methods and properties you will be using into an interface so that you can mock it with out tightly coupling to `RegistryManager`. You should not try to mock class you don't own.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the class that uses or depends on the `RegistryManager`

Comment: According to the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/csharp/service/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/RegistryManager.cs#L269), those methods are **internal** to the framework, which means that you should not be able to override them in your project.

Comment: @Nkosi Here is the class that uses the `RegistryManager`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KAZdSAnM)

Comment: How should I unit test the code without communicating with iothub?

Comment: abstract away the tight coupling to the RegistryManager. drafting up an answer for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you current version of the class to be tested

```
public class Registry {
    private readonly RegistryManager _registryManager;

    public Registry(RegistryManager rm) {
        _registryManager = rm;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetDeviceKey(string deviceId = null) {
        if (deviceId == null) {
            throw new Exception("Todo replace");
        }
        var device = await _registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
        if (device == null) {
            throw new Exception("TODO replace");
        }
        return device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey;
    }
}
```

If you want to test this then you will have problems with the `RegistryManager`. You need an abstraction of the services you want to use so that you can mock/fake them for testing without having to use the real thing.

something like

```
public interface IRegistryManager {
    Task<Device> GetDeviceAsync(string deviceId);
}
```

This will then allow you to refactor your class like this

```
public class Registry {
    private readonly IRegistryManager _registryManager;

    public Registry(IRegistryManager rm) {
        _registryManager = rm;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetDeviceKey(string deviceId = null) {
        if (deviceId == null) {
            throw new Exception("Todo replace");
        }
        var device = await _registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
        if (device == null) {
            throw new Exception("TODO replace");
        }
        return device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey;
    }
}
```

Which now allows your `Registry` class to be completely testable. You will notice that other than the type of the registry manager field nothing else needed to be changed. nice.

You can now make a fake `RegistryManager` or mock one up using testing frameworks as needed.

When you need to make the actual calls in your production code you just wrap the real thing in your interface and pass it into your `Registry` class

```
public class ActualRegistryManager : IRegistryManager {
    private readonly RegistryManager _registryManager

    public ActualRegistryManager (RegistryManager manager) {
        _registryManager = manager;
    }

    public Task<Device> GetDeviceAsync(string deviceId) {
        return _registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
    }
}
```

One of the good things with this approach is that you now only need to expose the functionality you really need to dependent classes.

Using `Moq` and `FluentAssertions` I was able to mock up and test the `Registry` class with the following test

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Registry_Should_Return_DeviceKey() {
    //Arrange
    var expectedPrimaryKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var deviceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var fakeDevice = new Device(deviceId) {
        Authentication = new AuthenticationMechanism {
            SymmetricKey = new SymmetricKey {
                 PrimaryKey = expectedPrimaryKey
            }
        }
    };
    var registryManagerMock = new Mock<IRegistryManager>();
    registryManagerMock.Setup(m => m.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId))
        .ReturnsAsync(fakeDevice);
    var registry = new Registry(registryManagerMock.Object);

    //Act                
    var deviceKey = await registry.GetDeviceKey(deviceId);

    //Assert
    deviceKey.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedPrimaryKey);
}
```

Hope this helps.