# How can I mock IotHubServiceClient for testing purposes? (v2)

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, azure-iot-sdk

I have a class `IotHubService` that depends on the C# IoTHub SDK's `IotHubServiceClient` (v2 version of the SDK, currently in preview) to perform various queries on an IoTHub. I'm trying to improve the reliability of my class by writing some tests and mocking dependencies:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetDeviceByIdAsync_ValidDeviceId_ReturnsDevice()
{
    // Arrange
    string deviceId = "testDeviceId";
    Device expectedDevice = new Device(deviceId);

    // Create a mock IotHubServiceClient
    Mock<IotHubServiceClient> mockIotHubServiceClient = new Mock<IotHubServiceClient>();
    mockIotHubServiceClient
            .Setup(c => c.Devices.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expectedDevice);

    // Create an instance of IoTHubService using the mock client
    IotHubService ioTHubService = new IotHubService(mockIotHubServiceClient.Object);

    // Act
    Device result = await ioTHubService.GetDeviceByIdAsync(deviceId);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedDevice, result);
    mockIotHubServiceClient.Verify(c => c.Devices.GetAsync(deviceId, default(CancellationToken)), Times.Once);
}
```

However, I'm unsuccesful in mocking the IotHubServiceClient and receive the following error when running my test:

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: mock => mock.Devices`

I understand that the underlying `DevicesClient` is sealed, but I was wondering if there is any way solve this problem?

Edit: What my `IotHubService` class looks like:

```
public class IotHubService : IIotHubService
    {
        protected readonly IotHubServiceClient _iotHubServiceClient;

        public IotHubService(string connectionString)
        {
            _iotHubServiceClient = new IotHubServiceClient(connectionString);
        }

        public IotHubService(IotHubServiceClient iotHubServiceClient)
        {
            _iotHubServiceClient = iotHubServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task<Device> GetDeviceByIdAsync(string deviceId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(deviceId));
            }

            try
            {
                return await _iotHubServiceClient.Devices.GetAsync(deviceId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to mock first the `Devices` property before you try to mock the `GetAsync` method. As I can see the `DevicesClient` has a protected ctor so, it is not really helping unit testing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `IotHubService` with Azure IoT, I am able to mock and test.

- Sample example with mock test and unit test.

```
public class IotHubServiceTests
{
    
    private const string ConnectionString = "  ";

    [Fact]
    public async Task CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        
        var iotHubService = new IotHubService(ConnectionString);
        var deviceId = " ";

       
        Device device = await iotHubService.GetDeviceByIdAsync(deviceId);

       
        Assert.NotNull(device);
        Assert.Equal(deviceId, device.Id);
        Assert.True(device.ConnectionState == DeviceConnectionState.Connected);

        
        if (device != null && device.ConnectionState == DeviceConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue: Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue: Failed");
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceNotFound_ReturnsFalse()
    {
        
        var iotHubService = new IotHubService(ConnectionString);
        var deviceId = "nonexistent_device";

        
        Device device = await iotHubService.GetDeviceByIdAsync(deviceId);

        
        Assert.Null(device);

        
        if (device == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceNotFound_ReturnsFalse: Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceNotFound_ReturnsFalse: Failed");
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CheckDeviceConnection_NullDeviceId_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
    {
       
        var iotHubService = new IotHubService(ConnectionString);
        string deviceId = null;

        
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => iotHubService.GetDeviceByIdAsync(deviceId));

        
        Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_NullDeviceId_ThrowsArgumentNullException: Passed");
    }
}

public class IotHubService
{
    private readonly RegistryManager _registryManager;

    public IotHubService(string connectionString)
    {
        _registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    }

    public async Task<Device> GetDeviceByIdAsync(string deviceId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(deviceId));
        }

        try
        {
            return await _registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
        }
        catch (DeviceNotFoundException)
        {
            
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running Xunit tests...");

   
    var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    var assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var result = Xunit.ConsoleClient.Program.Main(new[] { assemblyLocation });

    if (result == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Xunit tests passed.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Xunit tests failed.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**With  Mocking and Testing:**

```cs
 [Fact]
    public async Task CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        // Arrange
        var deviceId = "mytestdevice1";
        var mockRegistryManager = new Mock<RegistryManager>();
        mockRegistryManager.Setup(manager => manager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId))
                           .ReturnsAsync(new Device(deviceId));

        var iotHubService = new IotHubService(ConnectionString, mockRegistryManager.Object);

        // Act
        Device device = await iotHubService.GetDeviceByIdAsync(deviceId);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(device);
        Assert.Equal(deviceId, device.Id);
        Assert.True(device.ConnectionState == DeviceConnectionState.Connected);

        // Print the result of this test
        if (device != null && device.ConnectionState == DeviceConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue: Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CheckDeviceConnection_DeviceExists_ReturnsTrue: Failed");
        }
    }
```

- For more details refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180157/create-an-unit-test-for-azure-iot-hub-function-wit) [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/main/iothub/service/tests) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647213/unit-testing-a-class-that-uses-registrymanager-c-sharp-azure-iothub).

Comment: I don't see any mocks. What did you mock?

Comment: @PeterCsala for mocking refer this [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/1761)